# Galois Theory. Fixed Field. Find the minimal polynomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

> Let $k = \mathbb{F}_p$, and let $k(x)$ be the rational function field in one variable over $k$. Define $\varphi: k(x) \to k(x)$ by $\varphi(x) = x + 1$. Show that the $\varphi$ has finite order in $Gal(k(x)/k)$. Determine this order, find a $u$ so that $k(u)$ is fixed field of $\varphi$, determine the minimal polynomial over $k(u)$ of $x$, and find all the roots of this minimal polynomial.

I couldn't to find the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $k(u)$ (consequently, find all the roots) nor conclude $k(u) = \cal{F}(\varphi)$. I don't know if my idea is correct, but I'm going to write bellow.

> **Idea.** Note that
>   $$(\varphi(x))^p = \varphi^p (x) = x = \rm{id}$$
>   so, $o(\varphi) = p$. Take $u = x^p - x$, then we have
>   $$\varphi(x^p - x) = \varphi(x)^p - \varphi(x) = \underbrace{(x + 1)^p}_{\mathrm{char}(k) = p} - (x + 1) = x^p - x$$
>   so, since $\varphi$ fixed $u$ and fixed $k$ (by assumption), $\varphi$ fixed $k$ for all $k \in k(u)$. Then $k(u) \subset \cal{F}(\varphi)$ and $\cal{F}(\varphi) \subset k(x)$... ***how I prove that $\boldsymbol{k(u)=\cal{F}(\varphi)}$?***
>
> Now, $x$ is root of $p(X) = X^p - X - u$... ***Is this polynomial irreducible?***

Thanks for the any hint.

Comment: Consider $X^p-X-u$ as a polynomial in $k[X,u]=(k[X])[u]$. It’s of degree one in $u$, so irreducible. (Some details need to be checked, such as irreducibility as a $u$-polynomial over the polynomial ring being equivalent to irreducibility over $k(X)$, but that’s Gauss’s lemma.

Answer (score 2):

For proving equality: Notice that if $\frac{q(x)}{r(x)}=\varphi(\frac{q(x)}{r(x)})=\frac{q(x+1)}{r(x+1)}$ (where $q(x),r(x)\in k[x]$) then by properties of polynomials, $q(x)=q(x+1)$ and $r(x)=r(x+1)$. So for finding $\cal{F}(\varphi)=k(x)^{<\varphi>}$, we need to only work with elements of $k[x]$. Now, if $q(x)$ is fixed, then for any $a\in k$, $q(a)-q(0)=0$. So $x(x-1)\cdots(x-(p-1))=x^p-x$ divides $q(x)-q(0)$. Can you finish the proof?

To see that the polynomial is irreducible, we notice that it is equal to the polynomial $(X-x)(X-\varphi(x))(X-\varphi^2(x))\cdots(X-\varphi^{p-1}(x))$ which we know is the minimal polynomial of $x$.